# How to programmatically set NullValue property of DataColumn of ADO.Net DataTable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datatable, ado.net, dbnull

I have many new wizard-created DataTables in my project, which I need to extract data from. There are many **string columns with dbnull values** in these tables, which I want to extract as **empty strings**.

So I went ahead and changed the `NullValue` property of each `DataColumn` with `DataType` of `System.String` from `(Throw exception)` to `(Empty)` like this:

[image: Modifying the NullValue property of DataColumn in VS 2010]

I soon got tired of all the repetitive work, so I tried to set `NullValue` programmatically in the data layer of my application.

I was, however, *unable to even find* this property. I even decompiled the code of `System.Data.DataColumn` and the property `NullValue` did not seem to exist there. `NullValue` may be some magic feature of `Microsoft.VSDesigner.Data.Design.DataColumnEditor`, but that's nothing more than a mere suspicion at the moment.

How can I programmatically achieve the same effect as if I did set `NullValue` to `(Empty)` in the property editor)?

Comment: Did you try using the `DefaultValue` property?

Comment: Yes DefaultValue will work.

Comment: No, it won't work. Setting `DefaultValue` will only affect newly inserted rows. In my case the rows are **already present in the db**, I just load them and do want to access thier values through a strongly-typed datarow. I just double checked by actually trying: *does not work...*

Comment: the wizard generates a property where the getter returns the selected null value ... so you can't assign your null value just by setting a property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear: NullValue is not a property of the DataColumn class. It's a convenience setting of the TableAdapter code generator that can be set for each column. In practice, this means that setting this 'property' controls how the body of the column's property (Public Property () as  is generated. If, for example, NullValue is set to **(Empty)** then a conditional is added to the column property code to check for null and return an empty string. If NullValue is left to **(Throw Exception)** then this conditional is omitted from the property definition. 
As such, there really isn't a programmatic way to set this property, since you can't alter the tableadapter code at run time. However, you can create a new property (with a different name, such as MyColumnName_Safe) in a partial class for your TableAdapter that has the behavior you want. Just make sure to call the correct property instead of the autogenerated one in your consuming code

Answer (score 1):

Yes. DefaultValue property of DataColumn is not gonna work because you already have a number of prepared DataTables. Here is one possible solution =>
You can place all the tables in one DataSet (lets say ds) first then use the following code:

for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)

{

```
       for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[i].Columns.Count; j++)
          {
              if(ds.Tables[i].Columns[j].DataType==typeof(string))
              ds.Tables[i].Columns[j].DefaultValue = "empty string";

          }
```

}

Comment: Again: This is **not about default values**. It is about null values, that are already in the db. Default values (of any flavour) will not do any good, so your answer has no chance of working in my intended way. sry...

Comment: You cant do this just by setting a property

Comment: Can you provide some reasoning (I have my suspicions by now, but never got the time to check) in a separate answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Of **why** it is not possible

Comment: sure..I'll post it soon

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but the reason why it's not possible is that the `NullValue` property determines the code that Visual Studio generates for that column. If `Throw Exception` is selected, the code explicitly checks for `DbNull` and throws an exception if that's what was returned from the database. If `Empty` is selected the generated code instead returns an empty string when `DbNull` is returned. This is generated and thus compiled code, so you can't change this behavior programmatically at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio treats every datacolumn of any data table as separate entity that's why it doesn't provide any  efficient way to deal with all at the same time. So we don't have programmatically accurate solution for it.